# Example of a sequence such that $n(a_n-a_{n-2}) + b n(a_n-a_{n-1}) \to 0$ but $n(a_n-a_{n-2}) \nrightarrow 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Let $b \neq 0$. Do you know some example of a sequence such that $n(a_n-a_{n-2}) + b n(a_n-a_{n-1}) \to 0$ but $n(a_n-a_{n-2}) \nrightarrow 0$?

**Edit:** I also need that $a_n \to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $b=-{1\over 2},$ $a_n=(-2)^n.$ Then
$$n(a_n-a_{n-2})+bn(a_n-a_{n-1})=0$$
and $$n(a_n-a_{n-2})=(-1)^nn[2^n-2^{n-2}]$$

Comment: nice example, but are you sure about your last equality? I end up with $(-1)^n 3n2^{n-2}$

Comment: @Thomas Thanks. You are right. I have re-edited. I think with $b>0$ it can be harder to solve the problem.

Comment: Now i may  upvote without feeling guilty :-)

Comment: @Thomas I don't mind if you upvote feeling guilty. But I do mind if you downvote whatever your feelings are :)

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry because I forgot to put the condition $a_n \to 0$